# Erlang: how to know which process occupies network port and performs IO

Tags: erlang, erlang-ports

I need to know which Erlang process exactly occupies Network port(OS level) and performs IO when a Erlang program running? Is there someway to do this? Even better, some a little easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [observer](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/observer_ug.html#id59655) to get info on the ports that a process owns.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it.